# How to add a label above each bar in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to put a label within a bar chart in Highcharts. In my case above each bar which you can see here:

```
$(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Indicator per Sex'
        },

        xAxis: {
           categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Fev',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
               'Jun',
               'Jul',
               'Aug',
               'Sep',
               'Oct',
               'Nov',
               'Dez'
           ]
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Consults'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [
        {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 10, 20],
        color: '#FF0011',
        stack: 0
    }, {
        data: [30, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 10, 20],
        color: '#3333FF',
        stack: 0
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 10, 20],
        color: '#FF0011',
        stack: 1
    }, {
        data: [30, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 10, 20],
        color: '#3333FF',
        stack: 1
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 10, 20],
        color: '#FF0011',
        stack: 2
    }, {
        data: [30, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 10, 20],
        color: '#3333FF',
        stack: 2
    }]
    });
  });
 });`
```

I tried, but when I add labels appear one label each bar. So, how do this?!

Comment: Show us what you tried with the labels ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highcharts stackLabels will do the work.
[See here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels)

Answer (score 11):

add this to your series:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    rotation: 0,
    color: '#000000',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    align: 'center',
    x: 4,
    y: 0,
    style: {
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
    }
```

of course adjust as needed..
you can also add a `formatter` to add $ sign and commas for large numbers if you need it..

EDIT:
just saw it was bar chart..
you will need to add this to your plot options:

```
plotOptions: {
   bar: {
      dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
      }
   }
},
```

check out the bar [chart demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic) as well as their [api documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)

Comment: Ok I was able to add the title in each of the bars. Thank you guys!!

Comment: anytime! that's why we are here. an upvote or selected answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @PradoComp Could you share which option allows you set the label above each bar? Thanks